# How to Embed a section from another website/webpage into my website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, embed

How can I embed a section or a particular area from a website/web page to my website? Means, i want to display that section in my website.

Comment: use `iframe` with link to wanted page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use iframe to embed an entire page in to your web page like below.

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com" width="100%" height="50%"></iframe>
```

If you want to embed just a section from a web page you can't do it easily using HTML and CSS. There will be cross site issue as well.

You can use screen scraping to get the html section from the source page and you can then update your page with that source html content. To do this you might need to use jquery and ajax. Also be careful about security and authorization issues since you are scraping third party web page.

[What is Screen Scraping and How Does it Work?](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwic3O236K_xAhUijuYKHSBoChoQFjACegQIAxAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsearchdatacenter.techtarget.com%2Fdefinition%2Fscreen-scraping&usg=AOvVaw03vNWASkBisGMxKmjxqCM8)